# How can an openssl client trust a self signed certificate for a server

Tags: c++, c, openssl, handshake

I'm setting up an c++ class for handling tls connections (client and server).
It works except for the tls handshake :
I have generated my self signed root certificate and signed the rsa server key with it.
but i get a client error which is unknown CA

script to generate self signed CA (CA file and CA.pem file)

```sh
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -days 3650 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout CA -out CA.pem
```

script to generate and sign the server key (key file and key.pem file)

```sh
read -p "key and cert name :" x

openssl genrsa -out $(echo $x) 2048
openssl req -new -key $(echo $x) -out $(echo $x).csr
openssl x509 -req -in $(echo $x).csr -CA CA/CA.pem -CAkey CA/CA -CAcreateserial -out $(echo $x).pem -days 3650 -sha256
```

then I pass CA.pem to client using `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file`, key to server using `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file` and key.pem using `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file`

client is in mode `SSL_VERIFY_PEER` and server is in mode `SSL_VERIFY_NONE` so only client checks server certificate.

As the server key is signed using CA and client trust CA.pem it should be working but when handshake is negociated, i get this in wireshark (a message from client to server) : 
`Alert level Fatal, Description : Unknown CA`

Comment: *"i get this in wireshark"* -- why would you expect Wireshark to magically know that you're using your custom CA?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I suspect he means he sees a TLS message with type "Alert" in the Wireshark listing coming from the client.

Comment: @dbush ah, that was unclear, makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you read OpenSSL's documentation, for a client [SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file.html) installs a client certificate. It does not specify the list of trusted CAs that may be used to verify a cert.

For that, on the client side, you want to use [SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html):

> SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations() specifies the locations for ctx, at
>   which CA certificates for verification purposes are located.

Comment: thanks, i've changed for SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations and it works :)
However it only works with key.pem (certificate of the server signed by CA) and not CA.pem (self-signed certificate of the CA), i thought i could pass the CA certificate and it will validate all keys signed by this CA

Comment: Sounds like your CA cert has a problem that causes OpenSSL to reject it, or the server cert is not signed correctly. There could be many reasons for that. The specific error code from OpenSSL will often point to the reason why.

Comment: yep i just re-generated all my keys and it works now
thanks

Comment: just found the bug : Openssl does not like when both server and client (or CA and signed key) have exactly the same key description